# ksh and AT&T sed, break lines matching pattern

Tags: shell, unix, sed, ksh

I need to break 'aaa bbb' into

```
aaa
bbb
```

In one single line of code.
In gnused, I can:

```
print 'aaa bbb'  | sed 's/ /\n/g'
```

In bash, I can:

```
echo 'aaa bbb' | sed 's/ '"/`echo \\\n`/"
```

But in ksh/zsh, with at&t sed in AIX, none of this works:

```
print 'aaa bbb' | sed "s/ /`echo -e \\\n`/"
print 'aaa bbb' | sed 's/ '"/`echo \\\n`/"
print 'aaa bbb' | sed "s/ /`echo \\\n`/"
```

Is there any workaround in sed, with in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming exactly one space in the line:

```
sed 'h;s/^[^ ]* //;x;s/ [^ ]*$//;G'
```

To do this for *every* space:  (I think I am triggering a bug in my local `sed` here; I couldn't combine the commands as above)

```
$ echo aaa bbb ccc def ghi zzz |
> sed -e :s -e h -e 's/ .*$//' -e p -e x -e 's/^[^ ]* //' -e ts -e d
aaa
bbb
ccc
def
ghi
zzz
```

(You can see why GNU sed was extended to handle this case better.)  You can do all sorts of things with the hold space, and even more if you use conditional branching (`s/.../.../;thereifmatched`).

Comment: hmm, what if I need to do on long line like 'aaa bbb ccc ddd ...'

Comment: If you're using `ksh` and working with shell variables, you can actually avoid `sed` completely:  `${line#* }` is the stuff following the first space, `${line% *}` is the stuff before the first space.  Double the `#` or `%` to use the *last* space.

Comment: @MeaCulpa, see edited answer.  Or perhaps you'd be happier not looking; this is far from the most evil `sed` I've written, but it doesn't take much to go beyond most people's idea of evil.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
echo -e "aaa bbb ccc\nxxx yyy zzz" |
sed 'G;:a;s/ \+\(.*\(.\)\)/\2\1/;ta;s/.$//'
aaa
bbb
ccc
xxx
yyy
zzz
```

or perhaps:

```
echo -e "aaa bbb ccc\nxxx yyy zzz" |
sed -e 'G' -e ':a' -e 's/ \+\(.*\(.\)\)/\2\1/' -e 'ta' -e 's/.$//'
aaa
bbb
ccc
xxx
yyy
zzz
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this qualifies as 'on one line' or not...

```
print 'aaa bbb'  | sed 's/ /
/g'
```

... It's a single command, and I think that I've used on at&t sed (or whatever SCO Unix uses)  before...

Comment: Yes this is the most solid soluiton in reguardless sed and shell versions. I'm asking one-liner cos my friend need it in some strange automation suit which is simply broken in multi-lines. Anyway I convinced him entering the easy realm of awk. Thank you.

Comment: If the call needed to be on a single line, you could wrap it in a shell function. What solution did he use in awk?